# Problem resetting scroll when navigate a new page when using daisyui drawer in sveltekit

Tags: tailwind-css, sveltekit, daisyui

I am using a Tailwind Css Plugin Daisyui in my sveltekit app.

But I am currently facing some minor difficulties. After I wrap my layout contents with DRAWER, when I try to navigate to a new page, my current scroll height is not reset. It works fine without the DRAWER but does no longer scroll back to the top after adding the drawal. I really need you guys to kindly help me out with this.

Here is my **+layouts.svelte** code

```
<div class='drawer'>
    <input id='sidebar' type='checkbox' class='drawer-toggle' />
    <div class="drawer-content" style='scroll-behavior: smooth; scroll-padding-top: 5rem;'>
        <!-- Page content here -->
        <MainHeader />
        <slot />
        <MainFooter />
    </div>
    <div class='drawer-side'>
        <label for='sidebar' class='drawer-overlay'></label>
        <div class='menu p-4 w-80 bg-base-100 text-base-content'>
            <!-- Sidebar content here -->
            <MainSideBar />
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This was the solution to my scroll issue:
https://github.com/sveltejs/kit/pull/8723#issuecomment-1423522635

```js
/** @type {HTMLElement} */
let container;

afterNavigate(() => {
  container.scrollTo(0, 0);
});

/** @type {import('./$types').Snapshot<number>} */
export const snapshot = {
  capture: () => container.scrollTop,
  restore: (y) => container.scrollTo(0, y)
};
```